# How to open url in the current window instead of a new window in XUL?

Tags: javascript, html, xul

I'd like xul window  to ***always*** load pages in current window instead of new window 
I have 3 files in the same directory, 
`main.xul`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin" type="text/css"?>

<window xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<browser type="content" src="page_a.html" width="100%" height="100%" />

</window>
```

`page_a.html`

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="page_b.html" 
     target="_blank" >I'm page a, click to navigate to page_b.html</a>
</body>
</html>
```

`page_b.html`

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="page_a.html"
     target="_blank" >I'm page b, click to navigate to page_a.html</a>
</body>
</html>
```

- When i run the xul using xulrunner and click the link, the whole
  window disappear
- but i want to load the target page "page_b.html" in current window,
- I tried both `<browser>` and `<iframe>` approach, neither of them
  work.
- the window disappears as long as it tries to open a new window to
  load target webpage.
- If I replace `target="_blank"` to `target="_self"`, the code runs
  successfully.

  but the matter is what if i load a remote page that contains
  `target="_blank"` and is not written by me, for example
  http://www.google.com/ ?

So how to ***always*** load pages in current window despite the attribute
   of `<a>` element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to [implement `nsIBrowserDOMWindow`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/8bfe3372f848/browser/base/content/browser.js#l4123) and [set it to the window](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/8bfe3372f848/browser/base/content/browser.js#l787).

In your `openURI` implementation, you'd then call `.loadURIWithFlags` on your `<browser>` (compare with the linked implementation from  `browser.js`).

Comment: I use the xulrunner runtime downloaded from [here](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/xulrunner/releases/29.0/runtimes/xulrunner-29.0.en-US.linux-i686.tar.bz2) , and where is the `browser.js` file?   Is it located in `omni.ja` ?

Comment: It is part of Firefox (which is kinda a XulRunner app, after all). Follow the links in my answer ;)